# client - server program for transmitting text using signals SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2

Tags: c, posix, sigaction

server

```
typedef struct s_server
{
    unsigned char c;
    int counter;
}               t_server;

t_server server;

void    ft_one(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    (void)sig;
    (void)context;
    server.c += server.counter;
    server.counter /= 2;
    if (server.counter == 0)
    {
        write(1, &server.c, 1);
        server.c = 0;
        server.counter = 128;
    }
    kill(info->si_pid, SIGUSR1);
}

void    ft_zero(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    (void)sig;
    (void)context;
    server.counter /= 2;
    if (server.counter == 0)
    {
        write(1, &server.c, 1);
        server.c = 0;
        server.counter = 128;
    }
    kill(info->si_pid, SIGUSR1);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction act_one;
    struct sigaction act_zero;

    memset(&act_one, '\0', sizeof(act_one));
    memset(&act_zero, '\0', sizeof(act_zero));
    act_one.__sigaction_u.__sa_sigaction = ft_one;
    act_zero.__sigaction_u.__sa_sigaction = ft_zero;
    act_one.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    act_zero.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act_one, NULL) < 0)
        return (0);
    if (sigaction(SIGUSR2, &act_zero, NULL) < 0)
        return (0);
    printf("server pid: %d\n", getpid());
    server.c = 0;
    server.counter = 128;
    while (1)
        pause();
    return (0);
}
```

client

```
void empty(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    (void)sig;
    (void)context;
    (void)info;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    struct sigaction act;
    char *str;
    int serv_pid;

    memset(&act, '\0', sizeof(act));
    act.__sigaction_u.__sa_sigaction = empty;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    serv_pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    str = argv[2];
    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL) < 0)
        return (0);
    while (*str)
    {
        i = 128;
        while (i > 0)
        {
            if (i & (unsigned char)*str)
            {
                if (kill(serv_pid, SIGUSR1) == -1)
                    return (0);
            }
            else
            {
                if (kill(serv_pid, SIGUSR2) == -1)
                    return (0);
            }
            i /= 2;
            pause();
        }
        str++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

The screenshots show the result of work, programs. In the first case, I call the client several times. In the second with a lot of text. In both cases, apparently, the response signal from the server does not go away. Why? I can t understand
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HPTf.jpg).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBaUr.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text, they are not terribly useful. Post text as text instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "the response signal from the server does not go away"? What do you expect to happen differently?

Comment: In the client program, the exit from the "while (i> 0)" loop is possible only if an answer is received in response to the sent signal. I guess this is not happening for some reason.

Comment: Do you mean that the answer is *sometimes* not received? Or that it is never received? Try adding some debug printf statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition in the client program. There is no guarantee that the signal will be delivered *after* the client calls `pause`.

The correct way is to use `sigprocmask` and `sigsuspend`. Block incoming `SIGUSR1` with `sigprocmask`. After sending the bit, instead of calling `pause`, call `sigsuspend` with a mask that unblocks `SIGUSR1`. `sigsuspend` will return when the signal is caught, and block again.

```
sigset_t myset, oldset;
sigemptyset(&myset);
sigaddset (&myset, SIGUSR1);
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &myset, &oldset);

while (*str)
{
  ...
  // pause() -- wrong! race condition!
  sigsuspend(&oldset);
  ...
}
```